# How do I override http_proxy environment variable in Jenkins?

Tags: ant, selenium, jenkins, http-proxy

I have the following setup:

Jenkins -> Ant script -> Python script -> Interact with Selenium

I run Jenkins on a windows box. My Jenkins calls an Ant script which calls a python script which interacts with Selenium. The problem I have is that the `http_proxy` environment variable is defined and points to a proxy, that is intented to access the internet and not my system under test. When I run my Jenkins job I get a error message from the proxy along the lines that he could not access my system under test.

How can I disable the `http_proxy` in Jenkins so that it won't pass them to Ant -> Python -> Selenium?

Comment: Pardon me if this dumb.But shouldn't you be configuring the proxy in selenium rather than Jenkins? Isn't it your browser that tries to open the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to reset the variable in a build step before you run ANT.

Comment: EnvInject is exactly what I needed. It allows me to reset the `http_proxy` variable in the Jenkins Job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the variable in the jenkins settings page (override the default), or in the job (as a parameter). Both options will override any existing value on the system. Is this what you need?